# PySimpleGUI - updating a list item

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to make a simple trivia quiz inside of a GUI but I cannot seem to update the window so that it goes on to the next question. I have been trying for a while and whatever solution I come up with either works in part or crashes the window! Wondering if anyone could give me an idea of how to update the current window to show the following question?

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

questions = [
    Question(multiple_choice[0], "D"),
    Question(multiple_choice[1], "A"),
    Question(multiple_choice[2], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[3], "C"),
    Question(multiple_choice[4], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[5], "D"),
    Question(multiple_choice[6], "C"),
    Question(multiple_choice[7], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[8], "A"),
    Question(multiple_choice[9], "A"),
    Question(multiple_choice[10], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[11], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[12], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[13], "D"),
    Question(multiple_choice[14], "A"),
    Question(multiple_choice[15], "C"),
    Question(multiple_choice[16], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[17], "D"),
    Question(multiple_choice[18], "B"),
    Question(multiple_choice[19], "D")
]

sg.theme("DarkGreen5")
# All the stuff inside your window. This is the PSG magic code compactor...
layout = [[sg.Text()],
          [sg.Text(multiple_choice[0])],
          [sg.Text("Choose your answer:"), sg.Input()],
          [sg.Ok("Submit"), sg.Cancel("End Quiz")]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window("Logan's Quiz", layout)

# Event Loop to process "events"
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'End Quiz'):
        break
    if event == "Submit":
        for question in questions:
            answer = sg.Input()
            if answer == question.answer:
                window[multiple_choice[0]].update(multiple_choice[1])
window.close()
```

This is what I currently have!

I omitted the questions as they were not overly necessary to figure out the solution - I do not believe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- The input box name should be a generic name like 'question' since you will use the box for every question.
- Use the loop to go through the question list, updating the text box after each correct answer
- Access the question data through the question object instead of using the multiple_choice list

Try this code:

```
sg.theme("DarkGreen5")
# All the stuff inside your window. This is the PSG magic code compactor...
layout = [[sg.Text()],
          [sg.Text("Question")],
          [sg.Text("Choose your answer:"), sg.Input()],
          [sg.Ok("Submit"), sg.Cancel("End Quiz")]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window("Logan's Quiz", layout)

qcur = 0  # current question 
window['Question'].update(questions[qcur].prompt)  # first question

# Event Loop to process "events"
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'End Quiz'):
        break
    if event == "Submit":
        answer = sg.Input()
        if answer == questions[qcur].answer:
            qcur += 1  # next question
            if qcur = len(questions): qcur = 0  # restart list
            window['Question'].update(questions[qcur].prompt) # show next question
window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Mike - it is running back an error! However, your code has given me some ideas and a bit of inspiration! I will mess around with it!

Comment: There wasn't enough code in the post to test, so I had to guess :)  Hope it helps.